# is there any tool for determining which functions the program enter in runtime?

Tags: c, code-analysis

I need some tool to find out which functions of a code executes in a certain config and inputs; there are some code analysis tools but they show all functions flow of a code.

Comment: A profiler would provide such info.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I am not completely sure how specific you need the analysis to be. I've inserted a few links that may help you in your search.

In general, you can easily generate the so-called function [call graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph), which is a graph over which functions call which.

[Static analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) tools can do this in general. I've used Eli Bendersky's [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser) to generate call graphs for C code. Static analysis can only take into consideration what can be inferred statically, i.e. without running the code.

If you need higher precision and only want the resulting program-flow for a specific config + input, I suggest you use a [dynamic analysis tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_program_analysis), which performs analysis by running the code. One such tool is [valgrind's callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html), and [here is a tutorial](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2011/09/profile-c-application-with-callgrind-kcachegrind.html) that may be of use.